# Print preview is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printer

After adding the items to an online Sales POS system (http://sma.tecdiary.org/pos)

It displays a blank page when I try to use the print preview:

[image: Blakn Print Preview]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: **12345678**...why would you do that ?

Comment: Kindly Check the screen shot

Comment: Have you tried using any other browser ? Did you try reset google chrome or even create a new chrome profile ?

Comment: Actually This Login for Test Users

Comment: I Cleaned Up my Browser , but it's working on Firefox

Comment: Still not really a good idea to post it on public forums

Comment: I suspect this is Javascript which is **not** Java. In any case you should address this issue to the person you bought the script from.

Comment: No one is got this error !

Comment: I Bought from this link [http://codecanyon.net/item/stock-manager-advance-with-point-of-sale-module/5403161?s_phrase=pos&s_rank=17]

Comment: @sirushti What do you mean ? I am getting almost the same preview with little more text in it while using latest Google Chome in El Capitan

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Kindly Check it on Firefox

Comment: Why ? Fix it, so that it does work in Google Chrome as well. You don't plan to tell the same to your customers, do you ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how about the print window it says about blank.  Replace that with the website you want to print out. So copy and paste the URL from one window to the other. Maybe that will work.